# Do topic msg queues allow blocking reads

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there support for topic msg queues to allow blocking reads rather then callbacks.
I would like to synchronize two queues. Drive one by call back and wait on the other if a msg is not available. How would you sync two independent queues?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82361/do-topic-msg-queues-allow-blocking-reads./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-09-24**:
@rnunziata Mark the "check" sign at the answer if you're satisfied with it, instead of "closing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your question is actually about message synchronization, then please check [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters).

The `TimeSynchronizer` filter can subscribe to several topics simultaneously and will call back a single function with messages from all the topics as its arguments. This method will work only when the time stamps of **all** the messages are **exactly** same.

To synchronize the messages from sensors that are not synchronized in hardware, e.g. camera and laser, you may need to use [ApproximateTime policy](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy).

Regarding message queues you can find some information here: [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Advanced:_Using_Different_Callback_Queues).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-24**:
Thanks  a lot....still have much to learn